# View a child record's chatter feed from Parent record

Tags: chatter, related-list, custom, chatter-feed, ui

**The Problem:** Chatter feeds are powerful, but require the User to open the record to view it. When trying to centralise everything on a single Parent record, this does not make for a great UI/UX.

**The Question:** Does anyone know of an easy/light-weight way to display a child record's chatter feed on the parent record's lightning page?

Off the top of my head, I'm thinking about a VF page or lightning component solution which let's the user select a related record from a dropdown list and then displays the chatter feed for it below the dropdown list.

**Can anyone offer some sample code or point me to a 3rd party app for accomplishing this?**